# Is there a shortcut to the taskmanager on HTC tattoo

Tags: task-management, htc-tattoo

I can never end a task easily on the HTC tattoo - is there a shortcut to it I can make, or an easier app to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way I know is from the home screen click Menu->Settings->Applications->Running Services.  There are some task manager applications, though from what I've read they may be more trouble than their worth as far as bugginess and/or eating through your battery quickly.

Comment: Though this is on an Incredible.  I assume the menus are similar, especially since they're both HTC phones, but it may be a little different on your Tattoo.

Answer (score 0):

Personalize (lower right button on home screen)
Shortcut
Settings
Running services

This adds a shortcut to the Running Services screen to my home screen, HTC Thunderbolt with Sense 2.0 UI